# Accessing Advanced Custom Fields with Repeater using jQuery instead of PHP

Tags: jquery, advanced-custom-fields

I am using Advanced Custom Fields (with repeater) and am currently using the following code to access the fields, i.e.:

```
<?php if( have_rows('postage_prices') ): ?>

    <ul class="slides">

    <?php while( have_rows('postage_prices') ): the_row(); 

        // vars
        $order_qty = get_sub_field('order_qty');
        $strips_rp = get_sub_field('strips_rp');
        $strips_ep = get_sub_field('strips_ep');
        $roll_rp = get_sub_field('roll_rp');
        $roll_ep = get_sub_field('roll_ep');

        ?>

        <li class="slide">

            <?php echo $order_qty; ?>
            <?php echo $strips_rp; ?>
            <?php echo $strips_ep; ?>
            <?php echo $roll_rp; ?>
            <?php echo $roll_ep; ?>

        </li>

    <?php endwhile; ?>

    </ul>

<?php endif; ?>
```

My question is, instead of using PHP to access Advanced Custom Fields with Repeater as above, is it possible to access this information via jQuery?

Any existing examples on how to accomplish this, would be much appreciated.

Comment: Please do some research, specifically [search](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ajax+jquery) WPSE and the [net](http://lmgtfy.com/?q=wordpress+ajax+jquery), and update your question with an actual approach, best with code, you tried or trying to achieve.

Comment: Search the site for "AJAX API".

Comment: Will do but I really need help on how I would do the jQuery equivalent of the PHP code above.

Comment: with can you please give a little more clarification of how to implement this?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you registered or enqueued your jQuery script using `wp_enqueue_scripts` and assigned it a proper handle, this function will allow you access to the `postage_prices` fields in jQuery via a variable `postagePricesArray.prices`. *You need to replace `%YOUR_SCRIPT_HANDLE%` with your jQuery script's actual handle or this variable may not become accessible.*

```
function localize_postage_prices() {
  global $post;
  $id = $post->ID;

  if(have_rows('postage_prices', $id)) {

    $postage_prices_array = array();

    foreach(get_field('postage_prices', $id) as $price) {
      $postage_prices_array[] = array(
        'order_qty' => $price['order_qty'],
        'strips_rp' => $price['strips_rp'],
        'strips_ep' => $price['strips_ep'],
        'roll_rp' => $price['roll_rp'],
        'roll_ep' => $price['roll_ep']
      );
    }

    //
    // You need to replace %YOUR_SCRIPT_HANDLE% with your script's actual handle!
    //
    wp_localize_script('%YOUR_SCRIPT_HANDLE%', 'postagePricesArray', array(
      'prices' => $postage_prices_array
    ));
  }
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'localize_postage_prices');
```

Then in your jQuery file (which is enqueued and has a handle of *`%YOUR_SCRIPT_HANDLE%`*) you can access the array:

```
$(function() {

  console.log(postagePricesArray.prices);

});
```